# Return a XML field when using GROUP BY clause in MS SQL Management Studio?

Tags: sql, xml

I have the following table structure (partially excluded for clarity of question):

[image: lowFareResponse]

The table sometimes receives two lowFareRQ and lowFareRS that is considered to be only one booking under BookingNumber. The booking is then processed into a ticket where each booking number always have the same TicketRQ and TicketRS if the user proceeded with the booking. TicketRS contains 3rd party reference number.

I now want to display all the active bookings to the user in order to allow the user to cancel a booking if he wanted to.

So I would naturally want to retrieve the each booking number with active status as well as the TicketRS xml data in order to get the 3rd party reference number.

Here is the SQL query I started with:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
  [BookingNumber]
  ,[Status]
  ,[TicketRS]
FROM [VTResDB].[dbo].[LowFareRS]
GROUP BY [BookingNumber],[Status],[TicketRS]
ORDER BY [recID] desc
```

Now with MS SQL Management Studio you have to add the field [TicketRS] to 'GROUP BY' if you want to have it in the 'SELECT' field list... but you cannot have a XML field in the 'GROUP BY' list.
`The XML data type cannot be compared or sorted, except when using the IS NULL operator.`

I know that if I change the table structure this problem can be solved without any issue but I want to avoid changing the table structure because I am just completing the software and do not want to rewrite existing code.

Is there a way to return a XML field when using GROUP BY clause in MS SQL Management Studio?

Comment: Please don't judge me for table design, because I did not create it myself -mixing upper and lower camel case, using `Status` as field name and not normalizing where it was needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, this seems dirty... If your XMLs are identically *within the group*, you might try something like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,Col1 VARCHAR(100),SomeValue INT,SomeXML XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl(col1,SomeValue,SomeXML) VALUES
 ('testA',1,'<root><a>testA</a></root>')
,('testA',2,'<root><a>testA</a></root>')
,('testB',3,'<root><a>testB</a></root>')
,('testB',4,'<root><a>testB</a></root>');

WITH GroupedSource AS
(
    SELECT SUM(SomeValue) AS SumColumn
          ,CAST(SomeXml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XmlColumn
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
    GROUP BY Col1,CAST(SomeXml AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
)
SELECT SumColumn
      ,CAST(XmlColumn AS XML) AS ReCasted
FROM GroupedSource
```

Another approach was this

```
WITH GroupedSource AS
(
    SELECT SUM(SomeValue) AS SumColumn
          ,MIN(ID) AS FirstID 
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
    GROUP BY Col1
)
SELECT SumColumn
      ,(SELECT SomeXML FROM @tbl WHERE ID=FirstID) AS ReTaken
FROM GroupedSource
```

Comment: Considering that your solution needs a sub-query it is still not optimal for performance. For now I will just use code to nest queries (I know even worse) so that I can get it working until a rewrite (never in business terms).

Comment: @Nightwolf, If there is an idexed key, the second approach should perform quite well... Casting back and forth  is - for sure - more overhead...

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to `nvarchar(max)` and back

```
with t(xc,val) as  (
    select xc=cast(N'<x><y>txt</y></x>' as xml), val = 5
    union all    
    select xc=cast(N'<x><y>txt</y></x>' as xml), val = 6
)
select xc = cast(xc as XML), val
from (
    select xc = cast(xc as nvarchar(max)), val = sum(val)
    from t
    group by cast(xc as nvarchar(max))
    ) tt
;
```